# How to get Azure AD user's last login time?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am using the Azure AD Graph client library for .NET to retrieve and manage user accounts. I want to be able to find out the time stamp of the last login by a user. However the object returned from the library is of type Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User and does not contain any such property.

I am also unable to see any information related to login time on the Azure Management Console website. The Devices and Activity sections of a users profile are always empty, even for users i know to be active.

Answer (score 1):

Its a shame that Azure doesn't expose `last_logon` property of the User object,

Even the device entity has such property (`approximateLastLogonTimeStamp`)

Comment: see my answer below; it does (now?), but you NEED to add the properties flag

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree. On-premise AD includes this; it's disappointing that its not easier to get at in Azure AD (AAD).

One option, if your tenant has a P1 or higher AAD license, would be to use the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns/ endpoint.

You can get more info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-beta.

Answer (score -5):

I know this is a bit late, but this script did it for me:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp, whenCreated |

Select-Object Name,SamAccountName, whenCreated,enabled,@{Name="LastLogonDate"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\ExportUsers.csv –notypeinformation
```

P.s. this is a powershell script (so not the graph client library).

Comment: OP was asking about Azure AD, your script is for local AD